# Angular настройка AsyncPipe для постоянного получения данных с сервера (каждые несколько секунд)

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Я недавно работаю с Angular и еще не уверенно себя чувствую с библотекой RxJs, по этому - прошу вашей помощи. Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но ничего не получается. Лучшее, что получилось - приведу ниже в примере.

**Задача**:
Необходимо в веб-приложении Angular обновлять данные каждые 5 секунд. Для вывода данных использую AsyncPipe. Не могу понять каким образом можно настроить такую возможность. Если в ngOnInit единоразово получаю Observable объект и отдаю его в async pipe - все данные успешно выводятся, но при изменении данных на сервере - данные на клиенте не обновляются (что и логично. Нужно дергать сервер). Если я использую таймер - на клиенте видно, что постоянно происходит рефреш. У меня такое чувство, что мне вместо того, что бы присваивать новый Observable объект переменной tablesOrders$ - необходимо вместо вот такого таймера использовать какой-то оператор RxJs, что бы я не менял ссылку на объект, а обновлял текущий объект новыми данными (что-то вроде interval, но у меня не получилось его применить).

**TS**:

```
    export class TablesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

          @Input() myLocation$: Observable<Location>;
          @Input() myTables$: Observable<Table[]>;


    locationId: string;
    tablesOrders$: Observable<TableOrders[]> = new Observable<TableOrders[]>();
    private _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
      loading: boolean = true;

      constructor(private element: ElementRef, public dialog: MatDialog, 
         private operations: TableOperationsService, private router: Router, 
         private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

      ngOnInit() {    

        this.myLocation$.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)).subscribe(result => {

          if (isNullOrUndefined(result.locationId)) { return };

          this.locationId = result.locationId.toString();

          this.updateOrdersTask();

            });

          }
          updateOrdersTask() {
            timer(0,5000).subscribe(_=>{
                let orders$ = this.operations.getOrders(this.locationId)
                   .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy));
//вот здесь мы каждый раз присваимваем переменной новый объект
                this.tablesOrders$ = forkJoin([orders$, this.myTables$])
                    .pipe(timeout(5000), map(result => {
                  let tableOrders: TableOrders[] = [];
                  result[1].forEach(table => {
                let tb = new TableOrders(table,
                result[0].orders.data.filter(o => o.table.id == table.deviceID), result[0].waiter);
                    tableOrders.push(tb);

              });
              this.loading = false;
              return tableOrders;
            }),
              catchError(e => {
                this.loading = false;
                return of(null);
              }));
            return this.tablesOrders$;
          })
      }
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="query" *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-bar>

<div cdkDropList class="tables-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="!isNullOrUndefined(tablesOrders$ | async); else noTables">
  <div class="table-drag-box"
    *ngFor="let tableOrders of tablesOrders$ | async"
    cdkDragLockAxis="x" cdkDrag cdkDropListData="tableOrders"
    (cdkDragStarted)="swipeStarted($event)" (cdkDragMoved)="swipeMoved($event)"
    (cdkDragReleased)="swipeEnded($event, tableOrders)" (click)="showOrderDetails(tableOrders)">

<!-- здесь в различных элементах я использую переменную tableOrders которую получил из пайпа-->

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: создай пожалуйста пример на codesandbox, у тебя ужасно все очень запутанно, подписка внутри подписки и тд, не разберешься без реального примера. Еще и Observable через байндинг передается, и каждый раз рээсайнишь переменную для async pipe, букет :))))

Comment: @overthesanity да, есть такое)) Ок, сегодня вечером попробую, но обещать не могу так как сейчас я временно прыгнул на другую задачу. Контора дала возможность разобраться с Angular и по ходу дела сделать внутренний ресурс. В связи с этим - я не могу расшарить его "как есть", но могу попробовать сообразить что-то похожее. Хотя собственно - мне и не нужно непосредственно готовое решение, а скорее подсказка - как это правильно сделать (как это делают нормальные люди), а то гугл тольком не дает нормального ответа (возможно не знаю, как это правильно нагуглить).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо, давай попытаемся разобраться в твоей проблеме. Это сделать нелегко, потому что у тебя спагетти-код (без обид ). Давай попробуем из этих спагетти приготовить карбонару :)

---

Попрошу тебя в следующие разы вставлять отформатированный код, код, который ты вставил - неправильный, если я его копирую и вставляю в prettier, то prettier выдает ошибку.

---

И так, будем идти поэтапно по твоему коду, у тебя есть подписка на `myLocation$`, который передается через входной параметр. Внутри ты передаешь слушатель на событие `next`, делаешь проверку и вызываешь метод `updateOrdersTask`. Внутри метода ты подписываешься на `timer`, внутри слушателя события `next` ты создаешь поток, который передается параметром в конвеер `async`.

---

На будущее тебе говорю, что старайся вовсе избегать подписок в компонентах. Как не отписываться? Не подписывать вовсе. Подписки в компоненте в основном нужны в таких случаях, как отслеживание событий роутера через `Router.prototype.events` и так далее, где нет взаимодействия с шаблоном. Где есть взаимодействие с шаблоном, то достаточно просто создать поток и использовать `async` конвеер.

---

И так, нам нужно избавиться от подписок, для этого будем пайпить `myLocation$` на `timer` с проверкой на `undefined`, то есть нам нужно заменить этот кусок кода:

```
this.myLocation$.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)).subscribe(result => {
  if (isNullOrUndefined(result.locationId)) {
    return;
  }

  this.locationId = result.locationId.toString();

  this.updateOrdersTask();
});
```

На это:

```
this.myLocation$.pipe(
  filter(result => !isNullOrUndefined(result.locationId)),
  map(result => result.locationId.toString())
);
```

Далее, каждый раз как поток `myLocation$` генерирует событие нам нужно подписывать на `timer(0, 5000)`, за нас это сделает `switchMap` (другие операторы мапинга проекций типа `mergeMap|concatMap|exhaustMap` нам не подходят):

```
this.myLocation$.pipe(
  filter(result => !isNullOrUndefined(result.locationId)),
  map(result => result.locationId.toString()),
  switchMap(locationId => timer(0, 5000).pipe(map(() => locationId)))
);
```

Заметь я `timer` замаппил на `locationId`, чтоб не создавать хаос операторов.

Далее, после генераций событий от `timer` - нам нужно маппить проекцию на `forkJoin` и тот код, который внутри `map` у тебя:

```
this.tablesOrders$ = this.myLocation$.pipe(
  filter(result => !isNullOrUndefined(result.locationId)),
  map(result => result.locationId.toString()),
  switchMap(locationId => timer(0, 5000).pipe(map(() => locationId))),
  switchMap(locationId => {
    const orders$ = this.operations.getOrders(locationId);
    return forkJoin([orders$, this.myTables$]).pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      map(result => {
        const tableOrders: TableOrder[] = [];
        result[1].forEach(table => {
          const tableOrders = new TableOrders(
            table,
            result[0].orders.data.filter(o => o.table.id == table.deviceID),
            result[0].waiter
          );
          tableOrders.push(tableOrders);
          this.loading = false;
          return tableOrders;
        });
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this.loading = false;
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  })
);
```

Заметь, что я все это дело присвоил свойству `tablesOrders$`, не лучший код конечно же, но избавиться от спагетти он все равно помогает, ибо это код без побочных эффектов, не нужно переживать за таймеры и подписки внутри подписок, а также за гонки данных (какой таймер сгенерит событие раньше и тд), операторы это более explicit подход.

Есть еще одна проблемка - я не могу протестировать этот код, так как ты не привел воспроизводимого примера :( Так что, если что отпишись в комментах.

Comment: йомайо!)) Мои молитвы услышаны и боги ангуляра на них откликнулись) Спасибо за такой крутой ответ!) Добрался до этого проекта уже в пол первого ночи и уже просто нет сил тестить или создавать семплы, но завтра обязательно все сделаю! P/s: притиер использую, но когда из студии вставляю сюда код - он получается сильно размазан в ширину. Приходится руками переносить некоторые строки, что бы убрать скролл. Я прошу прощения, если что-то не так.

Comment: Рабочий код будет вот здесь: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ui-autoupdate Сегодня не хватило сил пофиксить все проблемы, что бы демка работала. Завтра уже наверняка добью. Как только будет готово - дам знать.

Answer (score -1):

Для таких случаев, когда нужна непрекращающаяся проверка, использовать async pipe слишком дорого!

Попробуйте добавить нечто вроде Socket.io. Работа с сокетами очень проста, и даже, если вы в первый раз с ними работаете, вы быстро сможете научиться.

Comment: AsyncPipe осуществляет подписку на изменения. Почему это может быть дорого?

Comment: Вот именно, что осуществляет подписку. В случае, когда это конечный набор вызовов, можно обезопасить себя через take(N) / takeUntil(...). В этом же случае - нет. 

Однако, сокеты гарантированно будут работать быстро и непонадобится таких костылей.

Comment: @DeniKuligin весь мир использует async pipe, а ты решил что это "слишком дорого"? что значит "сокеты будут работать быстро" - как ты это проверил? покажи бенчмарки? дружище, если не знаешь, лучше промолчать, чем сказать нонсенс...

Comment: Я .NET разработчик и в принципе я думал над тем, что бы использовать SignalR. Я понимаю теорию, но на практике не использовал. Сегодня вечером почитаю об этом. Сразу хочу уточнить два вопроса: 1) в случае с SignalR клиентом (или каким-то другим) - мы получим Observable объект или реальный? Для меня в общим это не очень то принципиально - я могу и на байндинг обычных объектов переделать, но хотелось бы понимать прежде чем действовать. 2) Я понимаю, что скорее всего здесь не .NET разработчики собрались, но вдрг... - нет ли ограничений на количество SignalR клиентов со стороны сервера?

Comment: Signalr отправит ровно то что попросите. Нет ограничений по формату.

Comment: Ваш  кейс не требует сокетов. Потому что вы запрашиваете данные циклично. Вот если бы вам нужно было бы оперативно реагировать на изменения в данных, то тут пожалуйста прикручивайте.

Comment: @Adug мое АПИ общается с рядом других АПИ, которые еще не дописаны. В идеале в дальнейшем так и должно быть, но есть часть функционала, которая зависит не от меня и на ближайшие пару месяцев это оптимальный подход. Потом мне сделают колбеки, мое АПИ начнет получать данные в момент их появления и идеальный вариант, что бы в этот же момент обработанные данные отправлялись на клиенты, которые подключены к АПИ. Так что сокеты мне будут нужны, но чуть позже. В любом случае - спасибо за ваше мнение!

Comment: @overthesanity Весь мир использует jQuery, зачем Angular. Кто сказал, что он лучше ? Покажи бенчмарки. 

AsyncPipe - не имею ничего против этого, однако, когда ты работаешь с самым дорогим - DOM'ом, то перерендер каждые 5 секунд - это слишком. При этом, не понятно, использует ли автор детектор изменений в формате onPush. Если нет, то это очевидно дорого, и надеюсь, не нужно объяснять почему? =)

Но, я думаю, что ты и сам отлично знаешь, что когда у тебя такие частые проверки, идеально использовать сокеты. Я привык думать о производительности приложений, чтобы не висли у клиента.

Comment: @Deni > `перерендер каждые 5 секунд - это слишком` ^_^  ))